# Converting Epoch Time to Human Readable Time in Powershell 'ConvertTo-Json' Outputs

Tags: windows, powershell, datetime, epoch, convertto-json

Powershell automatically converts all the date-time fields to Epoch time when using 'ConvertTo-Json'. Is there a way to prevent this from happening or changing it back to human-readable date-time? For example, check some of the fields in the output

Command:

```
Get-LocalUser | ConvertTo-Json
```

Output:

```
"PasswordChangeableDate":  "\/Date(1597311158786)\/",
"PasswordExpires":  null,
"UserMayChangePassword":  true,
"PasswordRequired":  true,
"PasswordLastSet":  "\/Date(1597224758786)\/",
"LastLogon":  "\/Date(1597238163431)\/",
```

Is there a way to prevent Powershell from converting the above fields into Epoch time, or converting them back to human-readable date-time?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are using Powershell 5 version. In Powershell 5 [`ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet is implemented using the `JavaScriptSerializer` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-5.1#notes). See this [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8#mapping-between-managed-types-and-json) to know the mapping between managed types and JSON equivalent.

| Managed type | JSON equivalent |
| --- | --- |
| DateTime | **Date object**, represented in JSON as **"/Date(number of ticks)/"**. The number of ticks is a positive or negative long value that indicates the number of ticks (milliseconds) that have elapsed since midnight 01 January, 1970 UTC.The maximum supported date value is MaxValue (12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM) and the minimum supported date value is MinValue (1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM). |

One solution I could think of is to convert the date to string([Using `ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_)) before serializing to JSON or to upgrade to [Powershell 7 :)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.1#example-1). This is because PowerShell 7 uses [Newtonsoft Json.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.1#notes) under the hood and the [default format used by Json.NET is the ISO 8601 standard](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm): `"2012-03-19T07:22Z"`.